# String color will not show in loop? Android

Tags: android

As you can see, I set the strings to be 2 different colors and tested it on the "complete" `TextView`, where it does change the string color. But once I place it on the `TextView` I have inside the loop, it only shows the `String` but not the color. How can I fix that? Thanks!

```
String red = " Missing";
SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(red);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
// **complete.setText(redSpannable);**

String green = " Complete";
SpannableString greenspan= new SpannableString(green);
greenspan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, green.length(), 0);

for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {

    int rem = ingnum.get(i) - (added[i] - 1);
    Log.v("Final", ingnum.get(i).toString());

    if (rem == 0) {
        jsonParsedfinal.setText(jsonParsedname.getText() + title.get(i) + greenspan + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Ingredients: " + jsonParseding.getText() + ingre.get(i) + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Link: " + jsonParsedlink.getText() + link.get(i) + "\n"

                + "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    } else {
        jsonParsedfinal.setText(jsonParsedname.getText() + title.get(i) + " " + rem + redSpannable + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Ingredients: " + jsonParseding.getText() + ingre.get(i) + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Link: " + jsonParsedlink.getText() + link.get(i) + "\n"

                + "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spannable buffer to merge your string

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append(jsonParsedname.getText()  + title.get(i));
int start = sb.length();
sb.append(" Complete")
 sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, sb.length(),  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

sb.append("Ingredients: " + jsonParseding.getText() + ingre.get(i) + "\n");
sb.append("Link: " + jsonParsedlink.getText() + link.get(i) + "\n");
jsonParsedfinal.setText(sb);
```

Comment: Thanks alot that helped! But if i run this on my For Loop now it only works for the last result only.

Comment: Also say i have 10 results, it shows everything correctly, but only on the 10th result the "Complete" is green

Comment: for that you need to put set text out side  the for loop